# NDsolve complicated function

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a complicated second-order ODE with NDSolve.  I've never used NDSolve before.  I've looked a lot of forums and tried some things, but I haven't been able to get the ODE's solution.  My code is

```
(* Constants *)
α = 0.04;
σ = 0.1;
A = 0.1;
θ = 10;
δ = 0;

(* Function *)
ϕ[i_] := i - θ/2 i^2 - δ

(* Calculated Boundary p *)
i = 0.5 (A + 1/θ - Sqrt[(A - 1/θ)^2 + 4 α/θ]);
p = (A - i) Exp[(ϕ[i] - σ^2/2)/α];

(* Symbolic Functions for ODE *)
L0 = (1 - z) (1 - z y'[z]/y[z]);
L1 = z (1 + (1 - z) y'[z]/y[z]);
c = 0.5 (A - 1/θ) + 0.5 Sqrt[(A - 1/θ)^2 + 4 α/θ ((1 - z)^2/L0 + z^2/L1)];
i0 = (1 - α/c (1 - z y'[z]/y[z])^(-1))/θ;
i1 = (1 - α/c (1 + (1 - z) y'[z]/y[z])^(-1))/θ;
m = z^2 (1 - z)^2 y''[z]/y[z];

(* Solve ODE *)
NDSolve[{α Log[c/y[z]] + ϕ[i0] L0 + ϕ[i1] L1 - σ^2/2 (L0^2 + L1^2) + σ^2 m == 0, y[0] == p, y[1] == p}, y, {z, 0, 1}]
```

All I get is "Infinite Expression" and "Indeterminate Expression".  Is this function too difficult for Mathematica?

Thank you,
Jane

Edit: The output is just NDSolve[...] with all the input just spit out again.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The ODE seems to be singular at both end points.

Comment: Side note: Comments in *Mathematica* are placed between parentheses + asterisks.  What you had before, words followed a semicolon, was actually a computation representing the multiplication of the words (and in general would have to be a syntactically correct expression, which would be computed, however long it takes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some progress can be made as follows in solving this equation.  First, replace all `$MachinePrecision` coefficients by exact numbers.

```
α = 4/100; σ = 1/10; A = 1/10; θ = 10; δ = 0;

ϕ[i_] := i - θ/2 i^2 - δ

i = (A + 1/θ - Sqrt[(A - 1/θ)^2 + 4 α/θ])/2;
p = (A - i) Exp[(ϕ[i] - σ^2/2)/α];

L0 = (1 - z) (1 - z y'[z]/y[z]);
L1 = z (1 + (1 - z) y'[z]/y[z]);
c =  (A - 1/θ)/2 + Sqrt[(A - 1/θ)^2 + 4 α/θ ((1 - z)^2/L0 + z^2/L1)]/2;
i0 = (1 - α/c (1 - z y'[z]/y[z])^(-1))/θ;
i1 = (1 - α/c (1 + (1 - z) y'[z]/y[z])^(-1))/θ;
m = z^2 (1 - z)^2 y''[z]/y[z];
```

Then, as suggested by Alexei Boulbitch, `Simplify` the ODE

```
eq = Simplify[y[z]^2 
    (α Log[c/y[z]] + ϕ[i0] L0 + ϕ[i1] L1 - σ^2/2 (L0^2 + L1^2) + σ^2 m)] == 0
(* ((5 + 2*z - 2*z^2 + 8*Log[Sqrt[(y[z]*(y[z] + (1 - 2*z)*Derivative[1][y][z]))/
   ((y[z] - (-1 + z)*Derivative[1][y][z])*(y[z] - z*Derivative[1][y][z]))]/
   (5*Sqrt[10]*y[z])])*y[z]^2 - 2*(-1 + z)^2*z^2*Derivative[1][y][z]^2 + 
   2*(-1 + z)*z*y[z]*((-1 + 2*z)*Derivative[1][y][z] + 
   (-1 + z)*z*Derivative[2][y][z]))/200 == 0 *)
```

As I noted in my comment last night, the equation is singular at both end points.  Nonetheless, it seems likely that the end points can be handled by expansions in `z` (as, for instance, Bessel's equation can be integrated numerically near the origin).  Here, to obtain a first cut at a solution, we simply move in from these endpoints by a small amount.

```
s = First@NDSolve[{eq, y[1/100] == p, y[99/100] == p}, y, {z, 1/100, 99/100},
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[1/100] == p, 
    y'[1/100] == Rationalize[0.1536914, 10^-10]}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Plot[y[z] /. s, {z, 0.01, .99}, AxesLabel -> {y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.  That's fantastic help.   I was aware of the singularity at the end points and I had tried perturbing them by epsilon but I couldn't proceed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you evaluate your equations together with its simplification:

```
eq = (α Log[c/y[z]] + ϕ[i0] L0 + ϕ[
    i1] L1 - σ^2/2 (L0^2 + L1^2) + σ^2 m // Expand //
 Simplify) == 0
```

you will find there such kind of terms:

[image]

The denominator under the logarithm and the square root turns into zero at `z->1; y[1]->y'[1]->p`:

```
(y[z] - (-1 + z) Derivative[1][y][z]) (y[z] - 
    z Derivative[1][y][z]) /. {y[z] -> p, y'[z] -> p, z -> 1}

(*  0. *)
```

So, the problem is in mathematics, rather than in Mathematica.

Have fun!

Comment: Isn't the problem rather the factors `z^2 (1 - z)^2` multiplying `y''[z]`, which bbgodfrey hints at in a comment?

Comment: @MichaelE2  Indeed, `y'[1] -> p` is not correct.  The slope is negative near the upper endpoint.